# from existing mysql database to EER diagram

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have one mysql database and it has 47 tables,all of the tables use the MyISAM engine,so it means there isn't foreign key constraints.
now I want to translate my existing database to EER diagram and I use mysql workbench.
the problem is when I translate the database,I just get 47 tables and there is no relation bwtween them,so I want to know if there is some way to get the EER diagram with some relation eg.1:n,1:1?

Comment: You can do so by manually dragging/dropping relationships. And yes, it won't be magically putting relationship in your schema design specially you are using MyISAM.

Comment: I just want to know if there is some convenient way！if this,I know!still thank you!

Comment: The answer is... of course... **NO**.. but hey! I saw this interesting [link](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) that might help.

Comment: this seems interesting!thank you very much!